# Getting error as "mapping values are not allowed" while creating a YAML file

Tags: java, selenium, yaml

I am not able to create YAML file for below code as red cross for 
 **variables** is being displayed ,due which I am not able to do further actions.

Here is the image - [image]

```
---
variables:
  'URL':"https://www.amazon.in/"
webelements:
  'SIGN_IN': 'xpath = .//*[@id='nav-link-yourAccount']'
  'Email_or_mobile': 'xpath = .//*[@id='ap_email']'
  'Password': 'xpath = .//*[@id='ap_password']'
  'login_button': 'xpath = .//*[@id='signInSubmit']'


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPnBp.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two errors in your file:

- no space after `:` in the second line (`'URL':"https....`)
- if you single quote scalar strings that contain single quotes you have to escape the single quotes with a single quote, or use double quotes. I use the former when the string contains double quotes or backward slashes, in addition to single quotes, the latter if there are no double quotes. (4 occurrences)

Correct YAML:

```
variables:
  'URL': "https://www.amazon.in/"
webelements:
  'SIGN_IN': "xpath = .//*[@id='nav-link-yourAccount']"
  'Email_or_mobile': "xpath = .//*[@id='ap_email']"
  'Password': "xpath = .//*[@id='ap_password']"
  'login_button': "xpath = .//*[@id='signInSubmit']"
```

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, please consider *accepting* it by clicking the ✔ (checkmark) next to the answer. That is the way other people know your problem has been solved, without reading the comments. It also changes the appearance of the question and this answer in lists. If a better answer comes along, you can always change the accepted answer.